# Outlook recurring appointment falling on a weekend

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to setup a recurring appointment on the same day of each month, but if that day falls on a weekend, I need to have it default to the last weekday. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve this is to check each occurrence individually and change it. I don't think there is a way to automate this.